# one-tozero or one mapping in Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

i have Person adn LoginAccount Class in which i want to make one to zero or one mapping. i.e one person can have zero or only one loginaccount.

i tried for this..
Person.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<id name="PersonID">
  <generator class="native" />
</id>


<property name="Title" />
<property name="FirstName"  />
<property name="SecondName"  />
<property name="ThirdName"  />
<property name="LegalFullName"  />
<property name="LegalFullNameLocal"  />
<property name="AliasFullName"  />
<property name="Suffix"  />
<property name="PreviousLegalName"  />
<property name="ReasonForNameChange"  />
<many-to-one class="OESPCS.Model.LoginAccount" column="LoginAccountID" name="LoginAccount"  foreign-key="fk_LoginAccountID_Person"  unique="true">

</many-to-one>
```

LoginAccount.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<class name ="LoginAccount">

  <id name="LoginAccountID">
    <generator class="native" />
  </id>

  <property name="LoginId" unique="true" />
  <property name="Password" />
  <property name="SaltKey" />
  <property name="PasswordChangedOnDate"/>
  <property name="IsPasswordChangeRequired" />
  <property name="IsKeepSignedIn" />
  <property name="IsMultiSessionAllowed" />


  <property name="PrivacyPolicyVersion" />
  <property name="IsLocked"  />
  <property name="LockedOnDate" />
  <property name="LockedTillDate" />
  <property name="IsDisabled" />
  <property name="DisabledOnDate"  />
  <property name="DisabledTillDate" />


  <property name="LoginFailAttempts" />

  <one-to-one class="OESPCS.Model.Person" name="person"  foreign-key="fk_LoginAccount_PersonID"/>


</class>
```

At DB this mapping gives me one-to-one mapping but in my project person may not have LoninAccount so in person table LoginAccountId can be null but as we are saying unique=true in person hbm so it does not allow for multiple times.

So i need to do one-to-zero or one mapping is this possible?

How to solve this problem?

Comment: what's the problem with  `unique="false"`? It isn't unique after all, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're new to NHinernate you should consider using a mapping-by-code technology such as Fluent NHibernate or NH-integrated automapping (introduced in 3.2).

The following sample code (Fluent NHibernate) should get you started:

```
public class LoginAccount 
{
public virtual Int Id  { get; set; };
public virtual string Password { get; set; };
public virtual string Saltkey { get; set; };

public virtual Person BelongsTo{ get; set; }

  public LoginAccount()
  {
  }
}

public class LoginAccountMap: ClassMap<LoginAccount>
{
  public LoginAccountMap()
  {
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Map(x => x.Password);
    Map(x => x.Saltkey);

    References(c => c.BelongsTo).Cascade.None().Fetch.Join().NotFound.Ignore();
  }
}

public class Person
{
public virtual Int Id  { get; set; };
public virtual string FirstName  { get; set; };
public virtual string SureName  { get; set; };

public virtual LoginAccount UserAcc{ get; set; }

  public Person()
  {
  }
}

public class PersonMap: ClassMap<Person>
{
  public PersonMap()
  {
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Map(x => x.FirstName);
    Map(x => x.SureName);

    References(c => c.UserAcc).Cascade.SaveUpdate().Fetch.Join().NotFound.Ignore();
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks Alex,but can we do it by mappin file which is writen in XML.i cant use fluent NH and i ll look out for NH 3.2.

Comment: by using the latest NH version you should be able to use both xml- and codemappings. Please keep in mind, that your program will become very static by using xml-mappings: changes to your buissnes objects (your model) will not be reflected nor automatically noticed by NH. As a result changing properties f.e. becomes very risky. This is why i woudln't recommand xml-mapping.

Comment: if this is no option for you, try out "not-found='ignore'" inside your "<one-to-one [...] />"-tag.